# How to setup r2dbc transaction properly

Tags: h2, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using spring-r2dbc and h2 for writing a transaction but am not sure about the proper transaction boundary setup.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class R2dbcApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(R2dbcApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
class Runner {
    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory cf;

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    //@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Mono<Void> runOnStartup(){       

        Mono emitter = Mono.from(cf.create())
                .flatMap(c-> Mono.from(c.setTransactionIsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE))
                        .then(Mono.from(c.setAutoCommit(false)))
                        .then(Mono.from(c.beginTransaction()))
                        .then(Mono.from(c.createStatement(
                                        "CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(255));")
                                .execute()))
                        .then(Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(60)))
                        .then(Mono.from(c.createStatement(
                                        "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES ('100','XXX');")
                                .execute()))
                        .then(Mono.from(c.commitTransaction()))
                        .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.from(c.rollbackTransaction()).then(Mono.error(ex)))
                        .doFinally((st)->c.close()));

        emitter.subscribe();

        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

From the CREATE statement above, once the table is created in the database, I am altering the column as `ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER DROP COLUMN name` through h2 console while the Delay 60 seconds executes, so the INSERT will fail giving an exception. But the transaction is not rolling back after the exception. How do I ensure either the isolation strategy is locking the table and ALTER statement fails or that the transaction can rollback and create table sql is rolled back. [reference doc I followed](https://r2dbc.io/spec/0.8.4.RELEASE/spec/html/#transactions.auto-commit)

application.yml

```
spring:
  jdbc:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:~/db/testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_MODE=3
    username: sa
    password:
    initialization-mode: always

  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:h2:mem:///~/db/testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_MODE=3
    username: sa
    password:
    initialization-mode: always
```

Exception

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [21002] [21S02] Column count does not match; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES ('100','XXX') [21002-214]
```

Comment: H2 doesn't support transactional DDL, `ALTER TABLE … DROP COLUMN …` commits an open transaction: https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_table_drop_column You can rollback only DML commands (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`, etc.)

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Will try DML commands as you suggested and will update shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly indicated by @Evgenij in the comment, rollback worked on DML commands. For testing I tried throwing `.then(Mono.error(new Exception("Expect Failure...")))` and verified the transaction rollback on simple DML and no transaction roll back for DDL commands.